# Clojure and SSL/x.509 certs quetion

Tags: ssl, clojure, x509certificate

I need to write a simple program for work that does the following:

1. read a config file
2. connect to a bunch of servers
3. establish a ssl socket
4. pull info form the server's x509 cert, expire date and hostname for now
5. email a report when its done

items 3 and 4 are things that I have had bad luck researching/googleing and I do not know java well, at all since 1.2 around 2001

Comment: It seems after posting I had a bit better luck with google:

http://oreilly.com/catalog/javacrypt/chapter/ch06.html

near the bottom of the page:

We now have the raw certificate data and can create a new certificate using getInstance() in the X509Certificate class:

    X509Certificate c = X509Certificate.getInstance(certificateData);

Having obtained an X509Certificate, Spill prints out various bits of information about it.

    System.out.println("Subject: " + c.getSubjectDN().getName());
(...)
    System.out.println("Valid from " + c.getNotBefore() +
        " to " + c.getNotAfter());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a code snipit that tells me what I need to know about java at http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.net.ssl/GetCert.html

here it is:

```
try {

    // Create the client socket
    int port = 443;
    String hostname = "hostname";
    SSLSocketFactory factory = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory();
    SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket(hostname, port);

    // Connect to the server
    socket.startHandshake();

    // Retrieve the server's certificate chain
    java.security.cert.Certificate[] serverCerts =
        socket.getSession().getPeerCertificates();

    // Close the socket
    socket.close();
} catch (SSLPeerUnverifiedException e) {
} catch (IOException e) {
} catch (java.security.cert.CertificateEncodingException e) {   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A verbose but throughout guide about the inners of Java Cryptographic Extension is found at Oracles website as well: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html

Comment: In my experience, people who ask questions about Java and SSL on StackOverflow expect a bit more guidance than just a link to the JSSE Ref Guide ;-)